# How to toggle class attribute when button is clicked using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, font-awesome

Here I try to change the class attribute. But I failed. How to toggle the class value.

```
    <button id="mybt" class="fa fa-plus"></button>

    <script>

       $("#mybt").click(function() {
       $("#mybt").toggleClass("fa fa-minus");
       });

    </script>
```

Jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/rajagopalx/u654oco8/

Comment: Have you included jQuery in your site? It's missing in your fiddle.
[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u654oco8/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be specific while using selectors. If you wanting to toggle fa-plus with fa-minus then you should only use those class name in jquery selector.

Also you should remove existing css class to show '+' icon and add css class to show '-' icon.

```
$("#mybt").click(function(){
    $("#mybt").toggleClass("fa-plus");
    $("#mybt").toggleClass("fa-minus");
});
```

My solution for above problem is http://jsfiddle.net/u654oco8/3/ check it out

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#mybt").on("click", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("fa-plus fa-minus");
})
```

Edited for your specific case